# why foreign key doesn't work in websql..?

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, foreign-keys, web-sql

i try to use foreign key in my app using web sql.. i test it in chrome.. no error.. but when i test with manual insert to table img (contain FK)
i expect to fail.. but insert is still succes..  this is my code.. please help me..

```
tx.executeSql("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");    
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS img (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,imgID VARCHAR, image VARCHAR,  FOREIGN  KEY (imgID) REFERENCES trans (ID) )", []);
```

i this case i try to use FK method for save my image name data and connect to trans table..

my insert code

```
tx.executeSql("insert into img (imgID,image) values ('100','23.jpg')");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `INSERT` performed on the same database connection as the `CREATE`? Because the `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` is only valid for the connection.  It has to be executed for each connection you open.

Also, make sure that you run that PRAGMA statement when you’re not in a transaction, since [that wouldn’t have any effect](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys).  Your example code starting with `tx.` suggests that is the cause of your problem.

**UPDATE**
As pointed out in the comments by [MisterSmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813951/mister-smith), extensions of Chromium-based browsers can't run SQL statements outside a transaction anyway, so no foreign key enforcement is possible.

So, you’ll have to ensure your foreign keys maintain integrity either in your application code, or you can write [triggers to enforce the foreign keys](http://www.justatheory.com/computers/databases/sqlite/foreign_key_triggers.html) (if triggers are permitted to Chromium extensions, that is).

Comment: I don't think this is a reliable approach, since PRAGMA is apparently disallowed in some browsers. Read [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=57218).

Comment: Yep, in Chrome I think it comes down to the `Database` (from `openDatabase(...)`) not having outside-of-transaction `db.exec(...)` (like e.g. React Native has) or similar and it needs to be executed as no-op (no operation) you have no way of doing so since no-op can't be done with pending `BEGIN` which is basically opening the transaction ... :-) So it may be that it's technically allowed, just not doable. Great link mr. Matrix virus @MisterSmith